# Arrow between terms of an equation with asymptote

Tags: latex, asymptote

I try to draw with **asymptote** one arrow between two terms of an equation

for example

```
pair position=(1,1);
label("$x^2+x+1=a+b+c$", position);
```

how to draw an arrow from $x^2$ to $a$ ?
Or is there a way to calculate the position of a term ?

pstricks and tikz allow to locate a portion of an equation
like this code shown by this link

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35717/how-to-draw-arrows-between-parts-of-an-equation-to-show-the-math-distributive-pr/35719

I would like to do it with **asymptote**.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

(of course I can hardcode the positions but my equation is more complicated, and does not support any modification)

Comment: Could you precise your problem? Drawing arrows between items in a text, an equation or whatever is easy and you have several solutions already given in your link. What do you want to do precisely and what are your attempts?

Comment: the link uses pstricks, some other solutions use tikz, but I try to do it with asymptote.

Comment: La même en français: Je souhaite tracer une flèche d'un point à une autre d'une équation avec asymptote Mais je n'ai trouvé que des solutions pour les utilisateurs de pstrciks et de tikz.

Comment: @TopMaths If you prefer French I can recommend https://texnique.fr/osqa/